# Concise way to initialize a block of memory with magic numbers

Tags: c++, initialization

A few examples of what I'm referring to:

```
typedef struct SOME_STRUCT {
  unsigned int x1;
  unsigned int x2;
  unsigned int x3;
  unsigned int x4;

  // What I expected would work, but doesn't; the 2nd parameter gets
  // turned into an 8-bit quantity at some point within memset
  SOME_STRUCT() { memset( this, 0xFEEDFACE, sizeof( *this ) ); }

  // Something that worked, but seems hokey/hackish
  SOME_STRUCT() {
    unsigned int *me = (unsigned int *)this;
    for( int ii = 0; ii < sizeof(*this)/sizeof(*me); ++ii ) {
      me[ii] = 0xFEEDFACE;
    }
  }

  // The far-more-verbose-but-C++-way-of-doing-it
  // This works, but doesn't lend itself very well
  // to being a drop-in way to pull this off on
  // any struct.
  SOME_STRUCT() :  x1( 0xFEEDFACE )
                 , x2( 0XFEEDFACE )
                 , x3( 0XFEEDFACE )
                 , x4( 0XFEEDFACE ) {}

  // This would work, but I figured there would be a standard
  // function that would alleviate the need to do it myself
  SOME_STRUCT() { my_memset( this, 0xFEEDFACE, sizeof(*this) ); }
}
```

I can't use valgrind here, and my options are limited as far as various debugging libraries I have access to -- which is why I'm doing it myself for this one-off case.

Comment: Try this: memset( this, reinterpret_cast<int>((unsigned int)0xFEEDFACE), sizeof( *this ) );

Comment: @Pubby8: memset() doesn't work, it takes an int parameter but fills with the lower 8 bits only.

Comment: @Pubby8: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/memset/ says `"Sets the first num bytes of the block of memory pointed by ptr to the specified value (interpreted as an unsigned char)."`

Comment: Why would you want a "drop-in way" to drop _that_ in?  It's kind of a unique situation.  I would go with the "C++ way of doing it".  If you really wanted to do it algorithmically, the variables should probably be in an array instead of separate values.

Comment: If you're using MSVC, you can use a nonstandard anonymous struct to help: `union { unsigned int xs[4]; struct { unsigned int x1; unsigned int x2; unsigned int x3; unsigned int x4; }; };` and then `for(int i=0; i<4; ++i) xs[i] = 0xFEEDFACE;`

Comment: I think your `sizeof(*this)/sizeof(me)` is a bug (for systems where `sizeof (uint*) != sizeof (uint)`)

Comment: @MooingDuck - If I'm attempting to find/demonstrate a problem for a single struct, it'd be less convenient to have to generate a list of all members (especially if the struct is at all complex) to initialize it the C++ way.

Comment: @sehe - good point, left out the dereference.

Comment: Pragmatically, I would give up on a 32-bit magic number and just use an 8-bit number. 42 is always good. 0xAA or 0x55 are traditional, as is 0xCC. If the goal is to detect some kind of uninitialized case, then the magic value might as well be 0xAAAAAAAA as 0xFEEDFACE or 0xBADBA6E1.

Comment: This question is purely about C++. Removing C tag.

Comment: @R - While the solutions some people are giving are C++, someone might want to do this in C as well.

Comment: Generally speaking, it's considered polite to give a reason why you down-vote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here’s a partial example of using `std::generate()` safely:

```
#include <algorithm>

struct Wizard {
    size_t i;
    static unsigned char magic[4];
    Wizard() : i(0) {}
    unsigned char operator()() {
        size_t j = i++;
        i %= sizeof(magic); // Not strictly necessary due to wrapping.
        return magic[j];
    }
};

unsigned char Wizard::magic[4] = {0xDE,0xAD,0xBE,0xEF};

std::generate(reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(this),
              reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(this) + sizeof(*this),
              Wizard());
```

(Of course, the endianness may or may not be right, depending on how you’re looking and what you’re expecting to see when you do!)

Comment: Your answer demonstrates the concept in it's simpler form. I think mine is a lot more userfriendly on the call site (it's _reusable_, for starters), a bit safer and equally flexible (the _magic_ being a static member; I don't have to put up with the external static for it though, by making it a function-scoped static - this is helpful for headeronly deployment))

Comment: You're right about portability.  I liked both answers (hence I +1d yours).  I went with this one for two reasons: 1) I don't need to worry about some of the constraints others have brought up such as non-POD types, packing, alignment, etc -- the structs I'm working with are entirely made up of POD types, with the only potential confounding factors being bit-fields unions, and endianness; and 2) using something like std::generate makes it possible to write this as a one-liner without a loop.

Comment: w/regard to the static, I changed that particular detail.

Answer (score 2):

I would declare this constructor:

```
SOME_STRUCT( unsigned int magic) : x1 (magic), x2 (magic), x3 (magic), x4 (magic) {}
```

This is very similar to your third option, and seems to be the natural C++ way of doing it.

Answer (score 2):

A point not made by others is this:

I think it is unsafe to do this for Non-POD types. Ironically, adding the initialization into a constructor makes it non-pod. Therefore I propose a freestanding function that checks for POD-ness statically (sample uses c++0x `type_traits` but you could use Boost as well)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_pod<T>::value>::type* FeedFace(T& v)
{
    static const unsigned char MAGIC[] = { 0xFE, 0xED, 0xFA, 0xCE };
    unsigned char *me = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(&v);
    for( size_t ii = 0; ii < sizeof(T)/sizeof(unsigned char); ++ii ) 
        me[ii] = MAGIC[ii % sizeof(MAGIC)/sizeof(unsigned char)];
}

struct Pod { char data[37]; };
struct NonPod : Pod { virtual ~NonPod() { } };

int main()
{
    Pod pod;
    FeedFace(pod);

    NonPod nonpod;
    // FeedFace(nonpod); // fails to compile (no matching function call)

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume this allows for nasty hacky stuff, like this:

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
int main(void)
{
    struct SOME_STRUCT {
        unsigned int x1;
        unsigned int x2;
        unsigned int x3;
        unsigned int x4;
    } foo;
    fill(reinterpret_cast<unsigned int *>(&foo),
         reinterpret_cast<unsigned int *>(&foo) + sizeof(foo) / sizeof(unsigned int),
         (unsigned int)0xDEADBEEF);
    cout << foo.x1 << endl;
    cout << foo.x2 << endl;
    cout << foo.x3 << endl;
    cout << foo.x4 << endl;
    return (0);
}
```

Basically abusing std::fill() with pointer casts.

Comment: This would violate the strict-aliasing rules.

Comment: Yeah, this is UB, even though it’ll work on many implementations. You might be able to get away with it with `__attribute__((__packed__))` or `#pragma pack(push, 1)` and `#pragma pack(pop)`, but I'd still be loath to use it in production. You could of course use `char*` to avoid breaking strict aliasing, but then you're back to splitting up your magic number.

Comment: @JonPurdy - Fortunately what I'm doing this for would only be used in a debugging environment.

Comment: 2nd parameter to `fill` could be, equivalently, `reinterpret_cast<unsigned int *>(&foo+1)`.

Answer (score 1):

You could `reinterpret_cast` `this` as a `char*` and then use `std::generate` with a predicate that rotates through the values you care about. If I get time later I'll try to sketch the code.

Also have you considered for example an LD_PRELOAD memory checking malloc library?

Comment: Yes.  I'm stuck waiting for approval for it, which can be painful; in the meantime I'm getting creative.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another hacky method.

```
SOME_STRUCT() {
    x1 = 0xFEEDFACE;
    memmove(&(this->x2), this, sizeof(*this)-sizeof(x1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Even if your `memset()` attempt did work, it makes an assumption about the structure packing and is therefore not guaranteed to be correct.  There is no programmatic way to iterate through the members of a struct and assign them in C or C++.  You will therefore need to be content with assigning the members individually.  Having said that, if you feel that you are comfortable with the memory layout of the structure and don't need to worry about portable code, you can just as easily initialize it with a for loop.

```
unsigned int i, *ar = (unsigned int *)&my_struct;
for (i = 0; i < sizeof(my_struct) / sizeof(unsigned int); i++) {
  ar[i] = 0xdeadbeef;
}
```